# Terraform got `Error: Computed attribute cannot be set` when I try to set dns_entry in endpoint definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

```
Terraform v0.13.5
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.16.0
```

## Description

I want to make an endpoint and want to set it into the Route53 record.
I will deploy a Kubernetes Cluster to the domain.

I got this error.

```
$ terraform plan

Error: Computed attribute cannot be set

  on route53.tf line 24, in resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "endpoint":
  24:   dns_entry = [
  25:     {
  26:         "dns_name" = "vpce",
  27:         "hosted_zone_id" = "ap-northeast-1a"
  28:     },
  29:   ]
```

```tf
resource "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
    name = local.cluster_name
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cluster" {
    zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
    name = local.cluster_name
    type = "CNAME"
    ttl = 30
    records = [aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry[0]["dns_name"]]
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "endpoint" {
  vpc_id       = module.vpc.vpc_id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ec2"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  security_group_ids = [
    module.vpc.default_security_group_id,
  ]
  subnet_ids = [
      module.vpc.public_subnets
  ]
  private_dns_enabled = false
  dns_entry = [
    {
        "dns_name" = "vpce",
        "hosted_zone_id" = "ap-northeast-1a"
    },
  ]
}
```

## What I tried

If I delete the dns_entry block, I got this error.

```
Error: Invalid index

  on route53.tf line 10, in resource "aws_route53_record" "cluster":
  10:     records = [aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry[0]["dns_name"]]
    |----------------
    | aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry is empty list of object

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

## What I want to know

In the case of creating an endpoint manually without terraform, I succeeded and got this DNS Name `vpce-0814cfe7cf6dd0f57-t6i209re.ec2.ap-northeast-1.vpce.amazonaws.com`

I want to set a DNS Name like that into the Route53 record with Terraform.

How to fix the error and set the DNS Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dns_entry` is what is returned to you after `aws_vpc_endpoint` creation. It is not something you can set yourself.

To get the `dns_name` and `hosted_zone_id` of the interface endpoint:

```
aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry[0].dns_name
aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry[0].hosted_zone_id
```

Usually you will have more then 1, so you either have to iterate over `aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry` or get them as lists.

Comment: I changed the code getting dns_name and delete the dns_entry block, but I got the same error as I tell in the What I tried section.

Comment: @Asuha The `aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry[0]["dns_name"]` is correct. But I don't understand what do you want to achieve. You want to create public `aws_route53_record` to private vpc endpoint? This is not possible.

Comment: Good point @Marcin but he could use a private zone here however no?

Comment: @RodrigoM Yes, but I'm not sure what is the OP's intention.

Comment: @Marcin I'm sorry for the bad communication. I'm a beginner of aws, so I maybe doing something wrong cause of my poor knowledge. I want to make a public vpc interface endpoint. The users access the domain and Route53 returns the endpoint to vpc that host Kubernetes Cluster.

Comment: @Asuha No problem. But there are no "public vpc interface endpoint". They are only used for private communication from vpc to aws resources. I would recommend reading up about how [vpc endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) work and what is their purpose.

Comment: @Marcin Now I understand that endpoint is not for the users. But private endpoint is also ok. I have to deploy Kubernetes Cluster and I guess that I can do that by using the endpoint. I will find another way to serve the access point for users.

Comment: @Asuha You would have to setup some kind of proxy for that, so that you can proxy public traffic to the vpc endpoints.

Comment: @Marcin I see. So I have 2 problems that terraform running error and setup proxy. Could you tell me the solutions if you have? Of course, answering only one is ok, or if you teach me the keywords to find solutions on google, that's very helpful for me.

Comment: @Asuha I already gave you the answer for your errors in your question, so I'm not sure what other issue you have? You can always make new question with new error details.

Comment: @Marcin As you say, continuing a long discussion in this chat even if I have a new problem is not beautiful. I will struggle to solve my problem again and if I can't find solutions, I will make another question page. Thank you very much for teaching me a lot. You answered my persistent question in good faith.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your hosted zone ID is incorrect :

```
hosted_zone_id" = "ap-northeast-1a"
  28:     },
```

That value should be the Route 53 hosted zone id for your domain. It appears to be a region id.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. Your answer will help me soon.

Comment: Greatl and Good luck. Please note Marcin is also correct. Looks like you are trying to modify the DNS of the enpoint itself. I think with both answers you can sort it out.